# Foreach цикл вывод путей картинок в img src из Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, img, redbeanphp

Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос.

Не выводит фотографии в цикле `forEach` в тег `<img src="./Download_Rent/"`

При этом если сделать дамп или `print_r` массива  выводит все данные корректно, если взять ссылку картинки и прописать путь в браузере, она открывается.

Может нужно данные получать используя другой цикл, например `while`? Может путь к файлу / папке по иному ставить?

Приведу часть из них. Единственное непонятно: на всех `string` значение либо `22` либо `23` - других цифр нет при `var_dump`.

```
array(135) { ["3624_5f0ce68b061f3.jpg"]=> string(22) "3624_5f0ce68b061f3.jpg" ["3624_5f0ce68b073d0.jpg"]=> string(22) "3624_5f0ce68b073d0.jpg" ["3625_5f12e9f9212ba.jpg"]
```

Данные получаю так для конкретно изображений. Все остальное выводит в плане данных, в данный момент вместо пути к фото из БД, выводит фото из команды `else   Photo/No photo.jpg`

```
$top3 = R::getAssoc('SELECT id, year, run, price, description FROM rent WHERE id IN (8321, 8319, 8320) ORDER BY time_upload DESC');

$img = R::getAssoc('SELECT photo FROM rent, rent_photo WHERE rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id');


<?php if (isset($top3)): ?>  
<div class="main">  
<div class="row">  
<?php foreach($top3 as $id => $ads): ?>
  <a href="ads.php/rent/<?=$id;?>">
  <div class="column">
     <div class="content">
       <h3><?php isset($ads['title']) ? $ads['title'] : null; ?></h3>     
       <h3><?=$ads['year']; ?></h3>

       <?php if(isset($ads['img'])): ?>
       
              <div class="fotorama" data-navposition="bottom" data-width="95%" data-nav="thumbs"data-thumbwidth="40px" data-thumbheight="40px">
                <img src="./Download_Rent/<?=$ads['img'];?>" width="95%">
       </div>
       <?php else: ?>
                <img src="Photo/No photo.jpg" width="100%">
       <?php endif; ?>
       <h3>Цена:  <?= number_format($ads['price'], 0, '.', '.'); ?> Р.</h3>
       <?php if (isset($ads['run'])):?>      
            <h3>Пробег: <?=number_format($ads['run'], 0, '.', ' '); ?>   км.</h3>
       <?php endif; ?> 
       <p><?=substr($ads['description'], 0, 120),'...'; ?></p>
       <button class="PreviewADS">Подробнее...</button>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>      
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: а что за переменная $top3 ? в запросе получаете результат в $img , а в цикле крутите $top3. странно, что вообще что-то выводится

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev   Спасибо за быстрый отклик. Дополнил код. $top3 делает запрос к 3 объявлениям из базы.

Comment: в селекте делаете выборку "SELECT id, year, run, price, description FROM ..", но там нет полей title, img. Можете заменить  "SELECT id, year, run, price, description FROM .." на  "SELECT id, year, run, price, description, title, img FROM .." ?

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev   Так вообще никакие данные не выводит. Если есть возможность, сформулируйте как бы вы выполнили эту команду и через какой цикл проводили. Буду крайне благодарен.

Comment: у Вас ошибка в запросе к базе данных. попробуйте выполнить запросы в базу напрямую и скопировать результат

Comment: @Eric7777777 прошу, все благодарности проявляйте в виде стрелки вверх, все технологии (redbean) если они важны в вопросе, указывайте в мета тегах а не в теле.

Comment: ну так же `isset($ads['img'])` возвращает `false`, потому что `["3624_5f0ce68b061f3.jpg"] => "3624_5f0ce68b061f3.jpg"` - вместо ключа `img` используется имя файла

Comment: @Gust  Как это исправить?

Comment: @Eric7777777, а таблица `rent` или `rent_photo` связана как-то с таблицей `sell`?

Comment: @Gust   Не связаны, мой косяк, там стоит rent вместо sell в коде. исправил. Решение до сих пор не получено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С учетом описанного комментария " Не связаны, мой косяк, там стоит rent вместо sell в коде. исправил. Решение до сих пор не получено."

Попробуйте строки

```
$top3 = R::getAssoc('SELECT id, year, run, price, description FROM rent WHERE id IN (8321, 8319, 8320) ORDER BY time_upload DESC');

$img = R::getAssoc('SELECT photo FROM rent, rent_photo WHERE rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id');
```

заменить на

```
$sql = "SELECT 
                    rent.id, 
                    rent.year, 
                    rent.run, 
                    rent.price, 
                    rent.description,
                    rent_photo.photo AS img
            FROM 
                    rent
            LEFT JOIN
                    rent_photo
            ON
                    rent.id = rent_photo.rent_id  
            WHERE 
                    rent.id IN (8321, 8319, 8320) 
            ORDER BY 
                    rent.time_upload DESC "; 
    
$top3 = R::getAssoc($sql);
```

Comment: Брат по коду! Огромное тебе спасибо!!!!!!!! Помог разобраться с вопросом который уже долгое время делал мне мозги!!! Здоровья тебе и успехов!!!!